# How to calculate FLOPs of transformer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, profiler

I know that

```py
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(graph, options=tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
```

can calculate the FLOPs.
But where can I find the graph of transformer?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph should be the tf.Graph of the model that you are profiling. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs) for more information about Tensorflow graphs and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/g3doc/python_api.md) for Tensorflow Profiler tutorials and examples.